# How does TravisCI decide which site to build through?

Tags: travis-ci

So I started using TravisCI for continuous integration today, and notice there was a .org and .com version.

I see that one's for open source and ones for commerical projects. I signed in with my GitHub on both sites because why not? I did not subscribe to any plans, I was still just building public GitHub projects.

My question is, when a build is triggered, what determines which TravisCI site it builds through?

I was noticing some strange behavior when deploying my firebase app with it. The .org version was succeeding while the .com version was failing. I realized it's because I stored my firebase token in the .org version but not the .com version.

I also initially setup a filter with my Gmail to catch the build emails. I initially received emails from the .com version. Then I began switching things around, deleting the firebase token from one, then running. I then started getting emails from the .org site.

So yeah, I'm just wondering what decides which TravisCI site runs the build? Does it matter?

Comment: This might explain you a little something : https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-05-02-open-source-projects-on-travis-ci-com-with-github-apps

Comment: @MaëlPedretti I had a hunch that both sites were building when triggered, and I think this pretty much confirms it. I also noticed that whenever TravisCI deployed, firebase was showing two deployments happening. So I guess it doesn't choose one or the other, if you have a project enabled on .org and .com, they both run. I turned the .org one off. Thank you for the link!